# When using bibliographystyle plainnat, how do I suppress automatic lettering of misc elements with the same author?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

When using the following TeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{centers2017underlying,
  title        = {\textit{Underlying Cause of Death 1999-2017 on CDC WONDER Online Database, released December, 2018. Data are from the Multiple Cause of Death Files, 1999-2017, as compiled from data provided by the 57 vital statistics jurisdictions through the Vital Statistics Cooperative Program}},
  author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://wonder.cdc.gov/ucd-icd10.html}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01},
}

@misc{icdcomparabilityratios,
  title        = {{A Guide to State Implementation of ICD-10 for Mortality; Part II: Applying Comparability Ratios}},
  author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/statab/document-for-the-states.pdf}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
% Create PDF on Linux: FILE=test; pkill -9 -f ${FILE} &>/dev/null; rm -f ${FILE}*aux ${FILE}*bbl ${FILE}*bib ${FILE}*blg ${FILE}*log ${FILE}*out ${FILE}*pdf &>/dev/null; pdflatex -halt-on-error ${FILE}; bibtex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && (xdg-open ${FILE}.pdf &)
```

Automatic lettering is added after each URL because the authors are the same (highlighted in red):

[image: Image of problem]

The automatic lettering may be overridden by specifying `year`, but I have nothing additional to put there.

Changing to `\bibliographystyle{plain}` solves the problem, but I need `plainnat`.

How do I get rid of this automatic lettering?

**Edit**: As suggested by one answer, adding `year` with a command that prints nothing still leaves a dangling comma (also used `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to make it easily visible):

[image]

Comment: Note that according to its title page `icdcomparabilityratios` actually has a year, namely `year = {2000},`. In this example there is no "a"/"b" any more once you add that year. (Of course the general question remains.) Note that it is in general not best practice to include formatting in the `.bib` entry: The `\textit{...}` spanning the entire title of `centers2017underlying` is something the style should take care of, not you. `plainnat` knows the `url` field, so you could say `url = {http://....},` instead of `howpublished = {\url{http://...}},`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I do have other cases without years, so as you mention, the general problem remains, but that's a valid point. I need an extra `{}` to maintain acronym capitalization, but you're right the italics aren't needed. I tried changing `howpublished` to `url` but it prefixes the URL with `URL` which is a bit odd, but I'll consider it. Cheers.

Comment: I do not recommend to enclose the entire title in curly braces to maintain the capitalisation of acronyms (or proper names) instead you should protect only those words that need protection: `title = {Underlying Cause of Death 1999--2017 on {CDC} {WONDER} Online Database, released {December}, 2018. {Data} are from the Multiple Cause of Death Files, 1999--2017, as compiled from data provided by the 57 vital statistics jurisdictions through the Vital Statistics Cooperative Program},` (maybe you see some of the program names as proper names and want to protect those as well)

Comment: Now that I read the title, that gives a strong case to make the year of `centers2017underlying` read `year = {2018},`

Comment: @moewe Good points, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to add some number of `\nothing` commands to the end of each otherwise-duplicated `author`. For example:

```
\newcommand\nothing{}
@misc{centers2017underlying,
  title        = {\textit{Underlying Cause of Death 1999-2017 on CDC WONDER Online Database, released December, 2018. Data are from the Multiple Cause of Death Files, 1999-2017, as compiled from data provided by the 57 vital statistics jurisdictions through the Vital Statistics Cooperative Program}},
  author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://wonder.cdc.gov/ucd-icd10.html}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01},
}

@misc{icdcomparabilityratios,
  title        = {\textit{A Guide to State Implementation of ICD-10 for Mortality; Part II: Applying Comparability Ratios}},
  author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics\nothing}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/statab/document-for-the-states.pdf}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01},
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of this workaround to your answer, to clarify how this can be applied?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that; added.

Answer (score 0):

Add something that doesn't show up:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @misc{centers2017underlying,
        title        = {\textit{Underlying Cause of Death 1999-2017 on CDC WONDER Online Database, released December, 2018. Data are from the Multiple Cause of Death Files, 1999-2017, as compiled from data provided by the 57 vital statistics jurisdictions through the Vital Statistics Cooperative Program}},
        author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics}},
        howpublished = {\url{https://wonder.cdc.gov/ucd-icd10.html}},
        note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01\noShow{a}},
    }

    @misc{icdcomparabilityratios,
        title        = {{A Guide to State Implementation of ICD-10 for Mortality; Part II: Applying Comparability Ratios}},
        author       = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention and National Center for Health Statistics}},
        howpublished = {\url{https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/statab/document-for-the-states.pdf}},
        note         = {Accessed: 2019-03-01\noShow{b}},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\providecommand{\noShow}[1]{}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I converted your example from `@article` to `@misc`, removed the year following the `\noShow` command (since I don't have a year to specify), and made the authors the same, and I see the same problem with a dangling comma.

Comment: Did you deleted the generated ``.bib`` and ``.bbl`` files before recompiling?

Comment: Yes, I removed those files. There is still a dangling comma after the URL. I edited my question to show a screenshot.

Comment: Put the ``\noShow`` in the ``note``. Also, the ``noShow`` parameter souldn't be the same in both.

Comment: Putting `\noshow` in the `note` and removing `year` did not work - automatic lettering is still added.